# PHP $_GLOBALS -> get values back?

Tags: php, global

Say I have a code that does something like this on startup:

```
if (!isset($_GLOBALS['something'])){
    getAndWriteToGlobals($x, $y)
}
```

which obviously goes to `getAndWriteToGlobals` function, which does few things and puts another data into `$_GLOBALS['something'][$ee] = $value ->` it works correctly (I printed the whole `$_GLOBALS['something']`) with `print_r` and everything is in there.

The problem I am having is when the program comes back from this function and i try to get the array in another variable like this

```
$var = $_GLOBALS['something'];
```

$var in this case contains nothing on printup(not even null), `count($var)` returns `0`.
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
function getAndWriteToGlobals($hostname,$community,$oidIndex, $oidValue) {

$indexes = snmprealwalk($hostname, $community, $oidIndex);
$values = snmprealwalk($hostname, $community, $oidValue);    

if (empty($indexes)) {
    print "Empty indexes array!\n";
}
else{ 
    $c=0;
    $a = array();
    foreach($indexes as $key => $indxVal){
        if (strpos($indxVal,'word') !== false) {
            preg_match("/[0-9]+$/", $key, $matches);
            $ind = $matches[0];
            $a[$c] = $ind;
            $c++;
        }
    }

    $i=0;
    foreach($values as $key => $value){

        if (strpos($key, $a[$i]) !== false) {
            preg_match("/[\+\-0-9]+$/", $value, $matches);
            $value = $matches[0];
            $_GLOBALS['something'][$a[$i]] = $value; 
            $i++;

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Your best bet for testing what's inside of variables is [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Try to use `var_dump($_GLOBALS['something']);` before and after the function to see if it changes it. If it unsets it, the only thing you can do is to show us the contents of the `getAndWriteToGlobals` function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using global variables in your application. It's an opening for a world of pain.

Comment: Do you mean the superglobal `$GLOBALS`? It's without an underscore.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php Yep, no underscore. PHP is nothing if not inconsistent.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It returns NULL, before and after. I ll update my question with code.

Comment: $_GLOBALS worked for me before...

Comment: @user1524316 that's not possible, unless the calls were in the same scope, or you did `global $_GLOBALS`. Either way, any variable name would have worked in those scenarios.

Comment: $GLOBALS not the underscore one.

Comment: I really don't know why $_GLOBALS worked before :( sry

Answer (score 0):

`$_GLOBALS` or `$GLOBALS`?

By the way, if you trying to create a global variable, be sure syntax:

```
// in somewhere (i think very first of master include file)
global $_GLOBALS;
$_GLOBALS['foo'] = 123;
// more code...

// and in function(s)
function getAndWriteToGlobals(...
    global $_GLOBALS;
    // do stuff with $_GLOBALS
```

PS: I don't recommend naming variable as PHP structure-like style. I prefer to name these variables like `$_globals` or `$globals` just (`$GLOBALS['globals']`, `$GLOBALS['cfg']` etc.).